# Как вывести все глобальные переменные?

Tags: javascript

Как в консоле броузера вывести все переменные объявленные через `const` `let`?

```js
const ENV = {
  'APP_ENV': 'local'
};

window.ENV = {
  'APP_ENV': 'local'
};

console.log(ENV);
console.log(window.ENV);
```

После выполнения скрипта я могу сделать так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: никак этого не сделать

Comment: @Grundy почему?

Comment: Очевидно, потому, что нет доступа к месту, где хранится список объявленных переменных :)

Comment: А как из скрипта? Т.е. только наугад?)

Comment: _А как из скрипта?_ - никак, я ж написал.

Comment: @Grundy правильно ли я понимаю, что в итоге есть переменная `window` и `ENV`? И почему она не стала свойством `window`?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107643/discussion-between-grundy-and-doox911).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В отличие от глобальных переменных объявленных с помощью `var`, глобальные переменные объявленные с помощью `let` и `const` не сохраняются в месте, к которому можно обратиться напрямую из скрипта.

Поэтому никак нельзя узнать список переменных объявленных с помощью `let` и `const` и вывести их.